# How to find files modified in last 24 hr but do not find from hidden directories and sum them

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, centos-6

I have following command to find files modified in last 24 hr and sum all of them.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /mnt/naspath -mtime 0 -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -n1 >> /tmp/size.log
exit 0
```

However it does also sum the files form hidden directory under `.snapshot`

What i see in find man page is I can exclude `.snapshot` with following which I do not clearly understand.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \)
```

So now I hope to exclude hidden and sum modified file with following command but this is doing totally opposite. It exclude `.snapshot` but sum up rest of all. `-mtime 0` is not being effected.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /mnt/naspath -mtime 0  -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \) | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -n1 >> /tmp/size.log

exit0
```

Anybody please know how to correct the command.
Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34451492/7552

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34451492/7552

Answer (score 1):

```
Add -not -path '*/\.*' to your command:

find /mnt/naspath -not -path '*/\.*' -mtime 0 -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -n1 >> /tmp/size.log
```